# Using fields from select query in where clause in subqueries

Tags: t-sql

I have a list of people and there are 4 types that can occur as well as 5 resolutions for each type. I'm trying to write a single query so that I can pull each type/resolution combination for each person but am running into problems. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT person,
   TypeRes1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 where table1.status = 45)
JOIN personTbl ON personTbl.personid = table1.personid
WHERE person LIKE 'A0%'
GROUP BY person
```

I have adjusted column names to make it more...generic, but basically the person table has several hundred people in it and I just want A01 through A09, so the like statement is the easiest way to do this. The problem is that my results end up being something like this:

```
Person  TypeRes1
A06     48
A04     48
A07     48
A08     48
A05     48
```

Which is incorrect. I can't figure out how to get the column count correct for each person. I tried doing something like:

```
SELECT person as p,
TypeRes1= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 
JOIN personTbl ON personTbl.personid = table1.personid
WHERE table1.status = 45 AND personTbl.person = p)
FROM table1
JOIN personTbl ON personTbl.personid = table1.personid
WHERE personTbl.person LIKE 'A0%'
GROUP BY personTbl.person
```

But that gives me the error: Invalid Column name 'p'. Is it possible to pass p into the subquery or is there another way to do it?

EDIT: There are 19 different statuses as well, so there will be 19 different TypeRes, for brevity I just put the one as if I can find the one, I think I can do the rest on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    person,
    (
        SELECT 
            COUNT(*) 
        FROM 
            table1 
        WHERE 
            table1.status = 45
            AND personTbl.personid = table1.personid
    ) AS TypeRes1 
FROM 
    personTbl
WHERE person LIKE 'A0%'
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works like a charm. Thank you so much! I was struggling with this for hours yesterday.

Comment: Thanks Arion!  You saved my butt with this one.  Also saved SO some server space since I don't have to ask the same question :)